# Can I reach a breakpoint when I press a button and call a function?

Tags: gui-construction, button, debugging

I have  a function and inside it I put a `breakpoint` on the first instruction in the function.

I made a `Button` which calls the function and when I press the `Button` to call the function the `breakpoint` is never reached despite the function being executed. This is the issue.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Of course I don't want to explicitly call the function since that is why I made the button , to quickly execute my function :(

```
filename = "paranthesis.c";
paranthesis = {"{", "["};

checkParanthesis[f_, p_] := Module[ {file = f, paranthesis = p },
  s = SetDirectory[
             "Z:\\C\\Users\\timo\\Desktop\\Study\\Softwareengineering\\Mathematica"];
  Print["The local directory is " , s];
  Print["The file is ", file];
  chr = StringCases[Import[file, "String"], 
                    RegularExpression["[(){}\[\]]"]];
  i = 1;
  rOpen = 0; bracketOpen = 0; accoladeOpen = 0; rClosed = 0; 
  bracketClosed = 0; accoladeClosed = 0;

  While[i <= Length[chr],
   Switch[chr[[i]],
    "(", rOpen++,
    "[", bracketOpen++,
    "{", accoladeOpen++,
    ")", rClosed++,
    "]", bracketClosed++,
    "}", accoladeClosed++
    ];
   i++;
   ];

  Print["Round Open ", rOpen];
  Print["Round Closed ", rClosed]; 
  Print["Square Bracket Open ", bracketOpen];
  Print["Square Bracket Closed ", bracketClosed];
  Print["Accolade Open ", accoladeOpen];
  Print["Accolade Closed ", accoladeClosed];
  ]


Button["Analyse File", checkParanthesis[filename, {}]]
```

Ps: this is an issue with the debugger not with the algorithm inside !

Comment: I think the only problem is a clash of scoping. If you remove the first definition of `paranthesis = {"{", "["};` then the function works to print your "exit".

Comment: Try `Method->"Queued"`.

Comment: For closers: neither of the comments seem to address the problem, as far as I can tell. It is not a simple mistake on OP's part but seems to be a limitation/bug in the debugger.